# How to compare dates in an array with a string of date?

Tags: python, numpy, date

I have a NumPy array of strings of dates like below.
I'm trying to select all dates <'1/31/2020' but I also see the dates that are in February?
my code is as below

```
for date1 in dates[dates <= '2020-01-31']:
    print(date1)
```

and the data looks like this array of dates

```
    1/1/2020
    1/2/2020
    1/3/2020
    1/4/2020
    1/5/2020
    2/4/2020
    .
    .
    .
    3/31/2020
```

Comment: What is the format of the array? Is `np.datetime64`? See also the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Have the dates in the standard ISO format `%Y-%m-%d` so that you can easily do a string compare: `date_array = [datetime.strptime(k, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for k in x]` and `filtered_array = [k for k in date_array  if k < '2020-01-31']`

Answer (score 0):

You are actually comparing them as string. As per your Req you can convert them to datetime obj or remove / or - before comparing.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y") <= dt.strptime("10/12/13", "%m/%d/%y")
```

Comment: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.ndarray I get this error

Comment: you need to pass indivdual element as in your loop

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your full code. What do you mean by *array*? A numpy array, a list, a pandas dataframe? A dict?

To subset dates you will need to convert your date string to a `datetime.date` object

Comment: It is a numpy array of strings of dates